# How to deploy <RecordTypes> metadata?

Tags: opportunity, metadata, record-type, deployment

I am trying to deploy RecordTypes from one sandbox to another. Here's my XML

```
<types> 
    <members>My_Opportunity</members> 
    <name>RecordTypes</name>
</types>
```

Fails to deploy, any idea what is wrong with this?

Comment: Giene, how is it failing ?

Comment: I think I am missing the object name which Brovasi has answered below. But wondering if the value in the name tag is still correct or not. RecordTypes or RecordType.

Answer (score 6):

Try the following:

```
<types>
    <members>Opportunity.My_Opportunity</members>
    <members>Opportunity.Other_Opportunity</members>
    ...
    <name>RecordType</name>
</types>
```

Comment: Is still the <RecordType> tag holds good or it should be <RecordTypes> ? Please confirm.

Comment: RecordType without the 's'. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_types_list.htm

Comment: Hi Brovasi, I went and looked into the example from the : [salesforce docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_recordtype.htm) However the "Declarative Metadata Sample Definition" example shows as recordtypes. Havnt retried yet, kind of waiting for a confirmation.

Comment: Some clarification, your recordtypes are included in your object files themselves. Open opportunity metadata and search <recordTypes>